# Comparing dates from from two different sources

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am using Tweepy API and storing tweets in a sqlite3 database. I am able to get the date and time using a function in Tweepy. it stores the value in the database as

```
2015-06-06 23:06:19
```

I then need to determine if the age of this date is greater than 30 days if so it needs to delete the row in the database.

```
c.execute ("DELETE FROM storedTweets WHERE tweetDate < DATE() - 30")
```

This is what I have so far but the query isn't deleting entries.

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm new to this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE()-30` does not return a date:

```
sqlite> select DATE();
2015-06-06
sqlite> select DATE()-30;
1985
```

But [using the `date` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html),

```
sqlite> select date('now','-30 days'); 
2015-05-07
```

Therefore,

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM storedTweets WHERE tweetDate < date('now','-30 days')")
```

---

Alternatively, you could compute the date in Python:

```
import datetime as DT
date = DT.date.today()-DT.timedelta(days=30)
c.execute("DELETE FROM storedTweets WHERE tweetDate < ?", [date])
```

Comment: c.execute("DELETE FROM storedTweets WHERE tweetDate <      date('now','-30 days')")

Works perfectly, Thanks.